# Conditional Formatting Based on Summary

Tags: crystal-reports, crosstab

I average compliance in my Crosstab with two separate measures over a single denominator. There are three summarized fields, `Avg. of Pre%`, `Avg. of Post%`, and `Sum of Denominator (count)`. I'm trying to conditionally hide the `Avg Pre%`/`Avg Post%` summaries when a equals zero.

In the case below, Nadia was out of office for January, so her count is 0, and her avg Pre and Post are 0%. She shouldn't be dinged for that, though. In February, Tim had average Pre% of 0%-- and he SHOULD be dinged for that, because he had a count of 617.

I tried using `currentfieldvalue`, but I'm not trying to hide Pre and Post based on their *own* values. I'm trying to hide them based on the `Count` value.  The column names and row names will both be dynamic, since the report runs for different time frames and groups of users.

```
                   Jan     Feb    Mar
Tim     Avg Pre%   10%     0%     50%
        Avg Post%  95%     32%    0%
        Count      327     617    500
Kerry   Avg Pre%   92%     51%    0%
        Avg Post%  87%     32%    0%
        Count      601     91     0
Nadia   Avg Pre%   0%      42%    32%
        Avg Post%  0%      31%    24%
        Count      0       902    540
```

Is there a better way to handle this?